# How can I find the NPCs I need to eliminate in Elite: Dangerous?

Tags: elite-dangerous

There are a lot of missions in the Bulletin Board which require you to eliminate someone. I did not manage to find a single one of them and I always ended up failing the mission even after an hour spent searching. What am I doing wrong? How do I find my targets fast? What are the leads?

In the last mission I failed the NPC was speaking in local chat while I was searching for him but I did not find him anywhere. I think that these missions are extremely hard compared to the smuggling missions I can get for the same rewards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unknown Signal Sources are one place.

Sometimes you'll see them flying around the target system in supercruise, in which case you'll need to find them (fly around a bit) and interdict them.

Comment: +1 for supercruise. That's where I've found most of the bounties I've taken out.

Comment: For those without an interdictor (like me), you can just follow them around until they drop out of supercruise. Then you can lock on to their wake. Once your distance/speed is at the safe drop levels for their wake, drop out of supercruise and you *should* drop pretty close to them. Certainly takes longer this way, but new players can't really afford an interdictor.

Answer (score 4):

You want to look almost exclusively for Unknown Signal Sources in their last known location/system. Its good to have an interdictor in case they jump away, too.

I have also found a target in Supercruise, after I had chased him away from an Unknown Signal source. I have never located one, personally, anywhere other than an Unknown Signal Source or a location they ran to from a source.

The wiki hints at USS's containing ["Unique NPCs"](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_Signal_Source), I think they're referring mainly to targets of bounties and/or missions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to locate Mission Targets quickly is the FSS (Full Spectrum Scanner), which is available on all ships by default.  To use it:

- enter supercruise
- use your D-Scanner (Discovery)
- set throttle (speed) to 0, still in supercruise
- enter FSS mode, default key mapped is ' (single quote)
- FOLLOW IN-GAME TUTORIAL SEQUENCE THAT APPEARS on first use!

Scan all the Unknown Signal sources in FSS mode. This is much faster than trying to aim your ship at them.  Mission related targets appear yellow or blue on your ship's systems (instead of white in the FSS).

It's beyond the scope of this question, but you can also scan all the planetary bodies and solar system locations.  This is key to mapping systems for extra exploration credits (from Universal Cartographics) as well as locating all sorts of interesting things.

It may be 8 years later but I ran across this and thought... these other answers aren't wrong, but there's a better way... so I'm leaving this just in case.
o7 CMDRs!